# pine escript tradingview who can give me a hand?

Tags: pine-script

I wanted to see who can help me with a code that I can't make it work the way I want. I'm not a programmer but I've been watching tutorials but I haven't got what I want. I'll attach some images so that you can visually know what I want to do.
[image: what I currently have]

now I attach an image where I indicate what I am looking for

[image: the modifications I need to make]

now an explanation of the second image: as you can see in image 1 the background color and the high or low line is not filled like the second image .. my idea is that the background color is in the form of a box, not as well as it is seen in image 1 if not as indicated as in image 2 ..
just as the high and low line match the background color it is assumed that in the time range I use is 07:00 to 17:00 I will leave the code with the configuration that I should use I hope someone can help me thanks!

```
 //@version=4
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/


study("High & Low Of Custom Session", shorttitle="High/Low Of Custom Session",overlay=true)

// Inputs
my_session = input("0700-1700", type=input.session, title='Custom Session')
Lines = input(true, title="Show High/Low Lines?")
FILL = input(true, title="Show Session BGcolor?")

// Determine if we are in a session
in_session = time(timeframe.period, my_session)
is_new_session(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

new_session = is_new_session("0600", my_session)

// Start of Session
is_newbar(res,sess) =>
    t = time(res,sess)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
new = (is_newbar("0600", my_session) ? 1 : 0)

// Plot Start Of Session
col_Start_of_Session = new_session and new==1? color.aqua:na

    

// In Session High/Low Calculations
var float _low = low
var float _high = high

_low := new_session? low : in_session ? min(low, _low[1]) : na
_high := new_session  ? high : in_session ? max(high, _high[1]) : na

col_low = _low == low? na: Lines?color.red:na
col_high = _high== high? na:Lines? color.green:na

// Plot High/Low Line
Low=plot(_low, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=col_low)
High=plot(_high, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=col_high)

// BG Color
Fill_col = FILL ? color.aqua:na
fill(Low,High, color=Fill_col)
//

// End of Session
start_of_session_value = valuewhen((new==1),high,0)
end_session_condition = start_of_session_value !=start_of_session_value[1]?0: in_session?1:0 
end_session = (end_session_condition == 0) and (end_session_condition[1]==1)? color.orange:na
```

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for cannot be done in Pine.
You can however make the lines start at the same bar, by using a `line` object.
A simple example is this:

```
var l1 = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.yellow)
var l2 = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.yellow)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(l1, bar_index-10, 1880)
    line.set_xy2(l1, bar_index,    1880)

    line.set_xy1(l2, bar_index-10, 1890)
    line.set_xy2(l2, bar_index,    1890)
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use a `line` object to create a `fill()`.

The reason why you can't get the lines to start at the same time with a `plot()` is that the `high/low` is not known on beforehand, and you cannot `plot()` in the past.
You could work around that limitation on historical sessions by using the `security()` function with parameter `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on`.  That will retrieve 'future' values.
But for today's session you're not able to do that, because the `high/low` for that session is not known until the session closes.

So, in conclusion, you'll have to choose between:

1. Using `plot()` and have a `fill()` background, but lines won't start a the same time.
2. Using `line` objects and have lines start at the same time, but no background color `fill()`

Edit: Code to play with
This will plot what you want, but it won't draw a straight line in a live session when new highs/lows are being made. All historical sessions will have straight lines thouhg.

```
//@version=4
study("Lookahead", overlay=true)

var float   daily_high  = na
var float   daily_low   = na

newSession = change(time("D"))

[hi,lo] = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [high,low], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot_color  = newSession ? na : color.green
fill_color  = newSession ? na : color.gray

plot_hi = plot(hi, "High", color=plot_color)
plot_lo = plot(lo, "Low",  color=plot_color)

fill(plot_lo, plot_hi, fill_color, 60)
```

Which yields this output

[image: Output]

Edit: Code configurable to draw only between a start and end time.

```
//@version=4
study("Lookahead", overlay=true)

var         session_info    = input("0700-1700", "Plot between these hours", input.session)

var float   daily_high      = na
var float   daily_low       = na


newSession  = change(time("D"))
inSession   = time(timeframe.period, session_info)

[hi,lo]     = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [high,low], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot_color  = newSession ? na : color.green
fill_color  = newSession ? na : color.gray

plot_hi     = plot(inSession ? hi : na, "High", plot_color, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot_lo     = plot(inSession ? lo : na, "Low",  plot_color, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(plot_lo, plot_hi, fill_color, 60)
```

Comment: images : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVTiq.png
this is a private indicator but i need one of my own this is what i'm looking for so i can play with the code

Comment: What is the time frame for the chart in your picture?

Comment: time frame on the chart is H1

Comment: I've added some code that does what you want with some extra info. Like I said, it can't be done (at least not in live sessions when new highs/lows are being made). But I think you'll perceive this as "this CAN be done" :)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! This can be useful to me, but how would I make it mark in a range of time? in this case from 07:00 to 17:00? I am very grateful for your help and take your time to help me

Comment: That depends. Are those times expressed in Exchange Time?

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/XVTiq.png  In the last image that I show, the box that marks are from 07:00 to 17:00.

Comment: I've added a 3rd code block that allows you to enable the plot only between certain hours (configurable with an input variable).

Comment: Wow if the time range works correctly but look at the following image the low or high does not enclose it as it should :( I leave image link https://ibb.co/sR7FFb0

Comment: I takes the high and the low between session breaks. Enable session breaks on your chart, and you'll see it.

Comment: My idea is that I take the high and low between 07:00 and 17:00 hours :(

Comment: I don't think you can lookahead to a specific session. Could you post the link to the original (closed source) script?

Comment: the script shows the 3 sessions in this case I only need one serious the one in new york I configure it at 07:00 to 17:00 this is the link of the private script : https://www.tradingview.com/script/Fvk73uEs/   
it's called Steady Swift by Hashtag_binary .. one more time I appreciate your help

Comment: As I suspected, the guy uses `plot()` for historical sessions, and `line()` for the current session. See this [screenshot](https://www.tradingview.com/x/PAWx5qVA/). Notice how the active session has no background coloring. Only the historical sessions have background coloring, as explained in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: that's what I'm looking for exactly that it shows like this in past tense in current day it doesn't matter, I care that it shows the historical data just like the private script does, Maybe I didn't know how to explain what I needed but I need like this just like that script does :(

Comment: In fact, if you see the settings of the script, you have the option of using the wick or body of the candle, since I have a base of the script, I would find a way to do that

Comment: I honestly don't know how he accomplishes the lookforward to a specific session. Sorry that I couldn't solve your problem, but I hope I've put you on the right track with my code examples. Another approach could be to contact the creator of that script, and ask him how he does it. You could refer to this stackoverflow question. Maybe he'll add something helpful.

Comment: my final idea would be the following to explain myself better .. when I add the same script 2 times to one I remove this option see the image https://ibb.co/6NKkm4b  and this would be the final result of my idea image : https://ibb.co/v4V0ngf

Comment: Both images are identical.

Comment: modify the second link of the image sorry check ibb.co/v4V0ngf

Comment: I've been trying to do it for months but I don't know anything about programming, it has cost me a lot to achieve it :(